# Intellij-idea / Android Studio, auto importing libraries mess up the whole file in Git

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-formatting

When I try to import a library by pressing the short cut command (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) or something, it automatically helps me import the library and have it at the top. After I hit save, however, the whole file seems to get replaced when I run `git diff`. This is obviously not a desired behaviour because it overwrites the history and git blame won’t work properly. Is there a way for me to auto import library, hit save, and the whole file will not get replaced???

Cheers, hope some Intellij-Idea expert could offer 2 cents

Comment: Maybe it happens because of the different line endings?

Comment: Bump anyone else? Is there a way to change it in the settings?  I have tried many different things and its still not working.  However, when I open it in atom, it seems to work properly.